# Sonar analyze for two languages

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Sonar newbie here. I am setting SonarQube up on my project. I have files in about 10 languages, but i'm interested in C# and C++ analyzis only. I know that you can analyze files in one language or every language, but is there a way to do it for exactly two languages? Any help or example would be appreciated as I really hope that excluding files is not the only option here.

Answer (score 3):

You can analyze as many language as you want.You want Multi-language Project.When you download the plugin for a particular language, you will see profile for every language. You can view those profiles under "Quality profiles" link like "Java profile" , "Xml profile", "c profiles" etc.Every profile will have a same name called "sonar way". In sonar.properties file while analyzing your source code, do not specify sonar.language rather specify sonar.profile=sonar way. In this manner it picks all the languages which is under sonar way profile. However sonar.profile has been deprecated but we still use it :-).However you should read this [page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-languageProject) for Multi-language Project . You can also  [provision](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Provisioning+Projects) the project to support Multi-language Project.They are many ways to do.You can opt whichever you like.

Comment: But When I create project in SonarQube I have to specify language then I can proceed further. In this case how can I scan Multi programming language project in scan